# What is the second parameter of stoi function in cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to use stoi function in cpp where I never clearly understood what the second parameter is and how we can tune it. Can someone give me an example where we can see the clear difference?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: You mean the `size_t*` output parameter that gives the number of processed characters, [as the documentation says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)? What exactly is unclear about that?

Comment: @Homer512 like how really it can be used and what difference using this parameter makes because as of now in all documentations which I have seen it was nullptr itself.

Comment: @john so If my string is "12345 2589" with stoi can I get 2589 of it?

Comment: There is an example here https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/. It shows this parameter being used to extract the portion of the string after the number.

Comment: @VALIVETISWAMYNAGASAINIVAS Yes, I've shown how to do that in an answer below.

Comment: Well, did you try reading [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)? It's clearly explained, you just have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol),

`size_t *pos    -   address of an integer to store the number of characters processed`

Also from the documentation:

> If pos is not a null pointer, then a pointer ptr - internal to the conversion functions - will receive the address of the first unconverted character in str.c_str(), and the index of that character will be calculated and stored in *pos, giving the number of characters that were processed by the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

An example (untested)

```
string str = "12345 2589";
size_t idx;
cout << stoi(str, &idx) << '\n';
cout << stoi(str.substr(idx)) << '\n';
```

Output

```
12345
2589
```